# GDBusProxy - Get input parameters in ready callback

Tags: c++, asynchronous, glib, dbus, gio

I am using `gdbus-codegen` to generate code. But basically I want to get parameters that were passed to `g_dbus_proxy_call() GVariant *parameters` inside `GAsyncReadyCallback callback`.

I don't want to use `gpointer user_data` for that because I need it for **`this`** pointer.

How do I do that?

https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusProxy.html#g-dbus-proxy-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
struct CallbackArguments {
    YourClass *that;
    GVariant *call_params;
}
```

and pass `CallbackArguments` as `user_data`.

Comment: Do you suggest to dynamically allocate memory for CallbackArguments and destroy it in the callback? Is the callback guaranteed to be called?

Comment: The standard approach is to dynamically allocate this closure, yes; and destroy it in the callback. The callback is guaranteed to be called exactly once, as long as the [`GMainContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) is iterated enough for the operation to complete.

This is the idiomatic way that all asynchronous operations using [`GAsyncResult`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAsyncResult.html) can be treated.